# Python precision in string formatting with float numbers

Tags: python, string, floating-point

I don't understand why, by formatting a string containing a float value, the precision of this last one is not respected. Ie:

```
'%f' % 38.2551994324
```

returns:

```
'38.255199'
```

(4 signs lost!)

At the moment I solved specifying:

```
'%.10f' % 38.2551994324
```

which returns '38.2551994324' as expected… but should I really force manually how many decimal numbers I want? Is there a way to simply tell to python to keep all of them?! (what should I do for example if I don't know how many decimals my number has?)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

*but should I really force manually how many decimal numbers I want?* Yes.

And even with specifying 10 decimal digits, you are still not printing all of them. Floating point numbers don't have that kind of precision anyway, they are mostly *approximations* of decimal numbers (they are really binary fractions added up). Try this:

```
>>> format(38.2551994324, '.32f')
'38.25519943239999776096738060005009'
```

there are *many more* decimals there that you didn't even specify.

When formatting a floating point number (be it with `'%f' % number`, `'{:f}'.format(number)` or `format(number, 'f')`), a *default* number of decimal places is displayed. This is no different from when using `str()` (or `'%s' % number`, `'{}'.format(number)` or `format(number)`, which essentially use `str()` under the hood), only the number of decimals included by default differs; Python versions prior to 3.2 use 12 digits *for the whole number* when using `str()`.

If you expect your rational number calculations to work with a *specific, precise* number of digits, then don't use floating point numbers. Use the [`decimal.Decimal` type](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) instead:

> - Decimal “is based on a floating-point model which was designed with people in mind, and necessarily has a paramount guiding principle – computers must provide an arithmetic that works in the same way as the arithmetic that people learn at school.” – excerpt from the decimal arithmetic specification.
> - Decimal numbers can be represented exactly. In contrast, numbers like `1.1` and `2.2` do not have exact representations in binary floating point. End users typically would not expect `1.1 + 2.2` to display as `3.3000000000000003` as it does with binary floating point.

Comment: The unrounded value of the closest IEEE 754 64-bit binary to 38.2551994324 is 38.25519943239999776096738060005009174346923828125

Comment: @Martijn Pieters `>>> 0.6 == 0.600000000000000009` yields `True`. Why tho ? :D it's because of the approximation you were mentioning ? Python `3.7.2`

Comment: @George all floating point numbers are approximations using binary fractions. See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: Binary fractions will not have infinite in precision.  As dividing by powers of 2 does not produce repeating decimals.  In general float is 6-9 digits, double is 15-18, long double 18-21, etc for its maximum precision when converted to decimal.

Answer (score 3):

I would use the modern [`str.format()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.Formatter.format) method:

```
>>> '{}'.format(38.2551994324)
'38.2551994324'
```

The modulo method for string formatting is now deprecated as per [PEP-3101](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101)

Comment: You now used the default `str()` format for floats, which *also* has a default number of decimals. If you were to use `'{:f}'` (or use `format(38.2551994324, 'f')` you'd pick a different default.

Comment: doh! I really love the % syntax :(

Comment: @KDawG: Not all Python developers agree. And *it doesn't matter here*, because you essentially are using `str(floating_point_number)` here! The OP could just use `'%s' % 38.2551994324` to the *same* effect!

Comment: Note: The deprecation message in PEP-3101 was never propagated to the Python codebase. Python versions all the way up to 3.4 (upcoming) support the syntax still. I *agree* that `format()` is better and has more features, but the `%` string syntax has been un-deprecated.

Comment: @MartijnPieters however you should avoid promoting the use of the modulo syntax because no matter what, that's the standard

Comment: Didn't I give enough feedback? You are basically using `str()` on the float value. Which uses a default number of digits (12) to display the value, which is not what the OP wanted, really. Try `'{}'.format(123456.789012346789)`, for example.

Comment: This isn't about `%` vs. `str.format()` (or `format()`), in any case, because *both* will behave exactly the same when applied to a floating point number; either you use `str()` *or* use floating point formatting (with `%f` or `f`, respectively).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Not quite.  Python 2.7.3: 
`print "{}".format(0.12345678)`
`0.12345678`
`print "%f" % (0.12345678)`
`0.123457`

Comment: @wallacer: both [String Formatting Operations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) and [String Formatting Mini-Specification](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) document the default precision for `f` as 6. I cannot reproduce your finding on Python 2.7.5.

Comment: @wallacer: ah, your first example should use `"{:f}"`! You are using plain `{}` which is the same as calling `str()` on the float. You've just illustrated my point.