# As an absolute beginner how do I use %.2f with variables in python 3.2.5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting

I just started to use Python for high school computer science, and I'm working with the `print` command. I'm learning about the `%.2f` rounding technique with variables, however, the lesson is unclear. I'm not sure where to put the `%.2f` in the string, and how to put the `%` sign with the variable. My code is below. Maybe someone can point me in the right direction?

```
Wage = 10.25 # sets wage as 10.25
Hours = 29 # sets hours as 29
Pay = Wage * Hours # uses hours and wage to determine pay
print("A student works for 29 hours at $10.25/hour. Their %.2f pay is", "$"+ %Pay)
```

Comment: _"print command"_ - Careful! `print` is no longer a statement in Python 3 but a function. Confusing will lead to unexpected behavior.

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586011/python-precision-in-string-formatting-with-float-numbers

Comment: Also, you may find [this site](https://www.compassclassroom.com/visual-latin-1) to be helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python precision in string formatting with float numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586011/python-precision-in-string-formatting-with-float-numbers)

Comment: @LauroMoura That's probably a helpful resource for Youssef, but it doesn't really look like a duplicate... or at least, I can't really tell. I think the confusion here is at a lower level.

Comment: This is the site for your formatting needs: https://pyformat.info/

Comment: If you're really using python **3.2.5**, as stated in the title, you should consider upgrading. This version is outdated ([May 2013](https://www.python.org/download/releases/3.2.5/)).

Comment: @FabienP I know it's out dated, it's just I have to use the same version as the school. Thank you though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bit of code you are asking about reduces floats to a certain number of decimal digits. Usage works like this:

```
num = 0.1234
print("%.2f" % num)
>>>> 0.12
```

`%` denotes the variable, and `%f` indicates that it is a float. `.2` states that you want two digits. The outer `%` denotes the variable you want to replace the inner `%` with.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of rounding is using `round`.

```
#The first number, 12345.54321 is what will be rounded. The second, 2, is how many decimals it will be rounded to.
round(12345.54321,2)
```